# Angle of View of a lens - C#

Tags: c#, angle

according to wiki viewing angle 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_view

**How to calculate this formula?**

[image: Formula]

I'm try:

```
double d = 36D;
double f = 50D;

double fov = (d/ (2*f);
double a = 2 * Math.Atan(fov);
```

thought is correct.
But the result is not correct! 
should give an answer 39.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result is **correct**; but C# returns it in **radians**, if you want **degrees** just convert

```
double d = 36D;
double f = 50D;

double fov = (d/ (2*f);
double a = 2 * Math.Atan(fov) * 180.0 / Math.PI; // <- 39.598...
```

Answer (score 3):

the result of atan is in radians.
convert in degree

```
double d = 36D;
double f = 50D;

double fov = (d/ (2*f));
double at = ((2 * Math.Atan(fov))* 180) / Math.PI;
```